# Xcode beta 7 - Do-While loop SWIFT Error

Tags: xcode, swift, do-while, xcode7, do-loops

The following code gives the error

> Expected 'while' in 'do-while' loop

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt"){
do {
    let stringFromFile = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var chapters: [String] = stringFromFile.componentsSeparatedByString("@")
    chapters.removeAtIndex(0)
} catch {
    print((error))
  }
}
```

it was working fine before, but now it's giving me an error. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

That code works for me as-is in the Playground with the appropriate Chapters.txt file in the Resources folder; XCode 7.1 Build 7B60. Did you try Shift-Command-K for a Clean Build?

[image]

Something does not seem right with your error message.  With Swift 2.0, there are no more `do-while` loops. They have been replaced by `repeat-while` loops instead. As your code snippet shows, `do` has been repurposed for `do-try-catch` error handling.

Comment: Silly me. smh. It was an error because i launched in an older version od xCode